# C : using strlen for string including \0

Tags: c, pointers

What I need to do is when given a text or string like

```
\0abc\n\0Def\n\0Heel\n\0Jijer\n\tlkjer
```

I need to sort this string using qsort and based on the rot encoding comparison.

```
int my_rot_conv(int c) {
  if ('a' <= tolower(c) && tolower(c) <= 'z')
    return tolower(c)+13 <= 'z' ? c+13 : c-13;
  return c;
}

int my_rot_comparison(const void *a, const void *b) {
  char* ia = (char*) a;
  char* ib = (char*) b;
  int i=0;
  ia++, ib++;
  while (i<strlen(ia)) {
    if (ia[i] == '\0' || ia[i] == '\n' || ia[i] == '\t' || ib[i] == '\0' || ib[i] == '\n' || ib[i] == '\t') {
      i++;
    }
    if (my_rot_conv(ia[i]) > my_rot_conv(ib[i])) {
      return 1;
    } else if (my_rot_conv(ia[i]) < my_rot_conv(ib[i]))
      return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get to the point that I compare two string that starts with \0, getting the -1 in the following example.

```
printf("%d \n", my_rot_comparison("\0Abbsdf\n", "\0Csdf\n"));
```

But this wouldn't work for a string with qsort because `ia++, ib++;` does work only for one word comparison.

```
char *my_arr;
my_arr = malloc(sizeof(\0abc\n\0Def\n\0Heel\n\0Jijer\n\tlkjer));
strcpy(my_arr, \0abc\n\0Def\n\0Heel\n\0Jijer\n\tlkjer);
qsort(my_arr, sizeof(my_arr), sizeof(char), my_rot_comparison);
```

and the array should be sorted like `\0Def\n\0Heel\n\0Jijer\n\0\n\tlkjer`

My question is how do I define the comparison function that works for the string that includes `\0` and `\t` and `\n` characters?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. The whole idea of C-strings is that there is exactly one `'\0'` and that it designates the end of the string. You'll have to write your own string handling functions.

Comment: Soddin' strlen() again... every time strlen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen` simply cannot operate properly on a string which embeds `\0` bytes, since *by definition of the function* `strlen` considers the end of the string to be the first encountered `\0` byte at or after the beginning of the string.

The rest of the standard C string functions are defined in the same way.

This means that you have to use a different set of functions to manipulate string(-like) data that can include `\0` bytes. You will perhaps have to write these functions yourself.

Note that you will probably have to define a structure which has a `length` member in it, since you won't be able to rely on a particular sentinel byte (such as `\0`) to mark the end of the string. For example:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int length;
    char bytes[];
}
MyString;
```

If there is some other byte (other than `\0`) which is forbidden in your input strings, then (per commenter @Sinn) you *can* swap it and `\0`, and then use normal C string functions. However, it is not clear whether this would work for you.

Comment: Or you could replace \0 and \t and \n for another symbol, use a mapping, do the operations, on the special string, then replace again.
Example:
\0 => 1  (as int values, meaning is ascii symbol for 1)
\n => 2
\t => 3
Or you can choose something that makes you comfortable

Comment: Fair enough. I was assuming in my answer that the real contract was "arbitrary bytes". I addressed this in an edit to my response.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use an extra `\0` at the end to terminate

```
int strlenzz(char*s)
{
  int length =0;
  while(!(*s==0 && *(s+1) == 0))
  {
   s++;
   length++;
  }
  return length+1
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but wouldn't work for e.g. data "abc\n\0" as encoding the ending with 2 NULs gives "abc\n\0\0\0", for which your `strlenzz` would report termination after `\n` and without including the trailing '\0' from the original data.

Comment: no, I'd imagine it would terminate with `abc\n\0\0`   ie a zero length string as the last string

Comment: Well, my point's just that the encoding isn't a general solution - it may or may not work with the OP's actual data, depending on whether there could be a trailing NUL in the data.

Comment: sure, my point is, given what the OP says, there is no general solution, either you need to know in advance how long the "string" is, or you need a way of indicating the end.  I've just given a general way of indicating the end  (in fact, I've seen this encoding in production systems before for lists of strings)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd prefer something like danfuzz's suggestion, but for the sake of listing an alternative...

You could use an escaping convention, writing functions to:

- "escape" / encode, expanding embedded (but not the terminating) `'\0'`/NUL to say '\' and '0' (adopting the convention used when writing C source code string literals), and
- another to unescape.

That way you can still pass them around as C strings, your qsort/rot comparison code above will work as is, but you should be very conscious that `strlen(escaped_value)` will return the number of bytes in the escaped representation, which won't equal the number of bytes in the unescaped value when that value embeds NULs.

For example, something like:

```
void unescape(char* p)
{
    char* escaped_p = p;
    for ( ; *escaped_p; ++escaped_p)
    {
        if (*escaped_p == '\\')
            if (*++escaped_p == '0')
            {
               *p++ = '\0';
               continue;
            }
        *p++ = *escaped_p;
    }
    *escaped_p = '\0'; // terminate
}
```

Escaping is trickier, as you need some way to ensure you have enough memory in the buffer, or to malloc a new buffer - either of the logical size of the unescaped_value * 2 + 1 length as an easy-to-calculate worst-case size, or by counting the NULs needing escaping and sizing tightly to logical-size + #NULs + 1....